# Redux - conditional dispatching

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

Classic problem - I want to validate a form before submitting it.

My submit button triggers an action (simple dispatch or thunk). If the form is valid, submit it - else, trigger an error message.

The simple solution: dispatch an action e.g. VALIDATE_AND_SUBMIT, which in the reducer will validate the form, and submit or set an error state.

I feel like these are two different actions: VALIDATE

```
{
   type: "VALIDATE",
   formData
}
```

This should validate and set errors.

```
{
   type: "SUBMIT",
   // get form data and errors from state
}
```

SUBMIT - should submit provided there's no error state.

Even if I use redux-thunk, I can't get feedback from the first VALIDATE action. Is my thought process anti-pattern here? How can I validate before submitting a form?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think part of your issue is think of actions as *something that is happening* rather than *something has caused the state to change*.

"Validate" is not an action.  "Validation failed" is the action.
"Submitting" the data is not an action.  "Data was submitted" is the action.

So if you structure your thunk with that in mind, for example:

```
export const validateAndSubmit = () => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        let formData = getState().formData

        if (isValid(formData)) {
            dispatch({type: "VALIDATION_PASSED"})
            dispatch({type: "SUBMISSION_STARTED"})

            submit(formData)
                .then(() => dispatch({type: "SUBMITTED" /* additional data */}))
                .catch((e) => dispatch({type: "SUBMISSION_FAILED", e}))
        }
        else {
            dispatch({type: "VALIDATION_FAILED" /* additional data */})
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My formData is stored in my state, so I can't access inside a thunk - how would you get around this?

Comment: there is a second parameter you can use in a thunk which is a `getState` function.  you can use it to get the current state from the store.   I'll update my answer to show this.

Comment: See this discussion on why Redux actions should have been called events to avoid this kind of confusion https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/891

Answer (score 0):

why don't validate form before dispatching, and dispatch the appropriate action? or you can use redux middle-ware [click here](https://medium.com/@meagle/understanding-87566abcfb7a#.twuyihny3)

Answer (score 0):

**Classical and whole solution:**

Hold the entire form in your state, for example:

```
{
  valid: false,
  submitAttempted: false,
  username: '',
  email: '',
}
```

Add `onInput` event to your form inputs and track their state validating on every change.

So when the user submits, you can check the valid state and react.

[**redux-form**](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/examples/simple/) 
was built just for that.

**Assuming you don't want to hold the entire form state**

In this case, you'll have to validate and then submit.

Here's an example assuming using react-redux with `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps`

```
// action in component
submitButtonAction() {
  props.validate();
  if(props.formValid) props.submitForm();
}

// JSX
<FormSubmitButton onClick={this.submitButtonAction} />
```

Comment: I do hold the form state in redux - so you're saying to validate and submit both in the 1 dispatch in the reducer?

Comment: Depends on the environment you run redux with. For example in a react component you create a method like I showed in the example above called `submitButtonAction` which calls 2 actions of validate then submit. But if you hold the form in the state, I suggested to validate on input to the form. You don't have to display the user if the form is valid or not, but it'll track it for you, in case the user clicks submit & the form is valid, things will proceed.